# Does God share all things with Jesus?

Tags: john, jesus, god

> "and what is mine is all yours, and what is yours is mine; and I have been glorified in them. "  Bible LXX Pbro. Guillermo jünemann beckchaefer

> and all things that are mine are yours and yours are mine and I am glorified in them John 17:10 MLV Modern Literal Version

> καὶ τὰ ἐμὰ πάντα σά ἐστιν καὶ τὰ σὰ ἐμά, καὶ δεδόξασμαι ἐν αὐτοῖς. John 17:10 NAS28

Is it a complete mutual and reciprocal relationship of both parties?

Answer (score 4):

As God, the Father has authority to give as He desires.  Jesus, as God's Son, and the Son of Man, has been given all things by the Father.

> The Father loveth the Son, and hath given **all things** into his hand.
> (John 3:35, KJV)

Even the right to be worshiped has been given to the Son.

> And again, when he bringeth in the firstbegotten into the world, he
> saith, And let all the angels of God worship him. (Hebrews 1:6, KJV)

Naturally, if Jesus had been God, he would never have needed to receive all these things of God--they would already have been his.  But God has given him "all things," just as God wants to give *us* all things that we might need.

> But seek ye first the kingdom of God, and his righteousness; and **all
> these things** shall be added unto you. (Matthew 6:33, KJV)